Implementing Stochastic Quantization Numerically
The stochastic quantization method of Parisi and Wu is defines the stochastic PDE
$$d\phi = -\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}ds + dw_s$$
where $w_s$ is a spacetime white noise. The physical content of the theory is encoded in the $s \to \infty$ limit (see, for reference, Namiki's Stochastic Quantization).
What does a spacetime white noise mean, numerically, and how is the equation solved?
If one tries to numerically solve the equation by discretizing the space(time) dimensions and iteratively solving it along the $s$-axis as if it were a set of lower dimensional SDE's, the lower dimensional white noise term drives the final paths to be discontinuous, but discontinuous paths can't contribute to physical quantities appearing with the path integral because of the exponential suppression of the divergent kinetic term. How are paths generated in this way?
The literature seems full of papers explaining the theory, but I'm having difficulty finding something that details the computation. It's possible that I'm simply implementing it incorrectly, but the section in Namiki isn't enough for me because of the discontinuity issue I find.
